# Help with Pointwise and Uniform Convergence in Metric Spaces

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, proof-verification

I am having a bit of difficulty understanding uniform convergence and would also like to check my understanding of pointwise convergence.

Using the example of $f_n$(x) = $x^n$ on (-1,1), I found the pointwise limit by checking the limit when x is between -1 and 0, at 0, and between 0 and 1. I found that the limit would be 0 in every case. Is this sequence of functions pointwise convergent because all of the limits equal 0 or because all of them have a limit? For example, would $f_n$(x) = $x^n$ on (-1,1] still be pointwise convergent if the limit at x = 1 is 1?

I also do not know how to find if $f_n$(x) = $x^n$ on (-1,1) is uniformly convergent - I understand that you must find an ϵ that works for each x, but I don't know how to go about that with $f_n$(x) = $x^n$. Could you possible walk me through this?

This is not homework, I would just like an explanation of how to find epsilon, and you may use a different example if desired.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to mention the second case when the interval we are considering is $(-1,1]$. This convergence is not uniform anymore.

To see this, take $x_n=(1-\frac{1}{n})$ then we have

$\left | f(x_n)-0 \right |=\left | (1-\frac{1}{n})^n \right |=(1-\frac{1}{n})^n$

So $\lim_{n \to \infty }(1-\frac{1}{n})^n=e^{-1} > 0$

Then $\exists \varepsilon =e^{-1}$  and sequence $x_{n} \in (-1,1]$ and a natural number $N_{0}$ such that
  $\forall n>N_{0}$, we have $\left | f(x_n)-0 \right |>e^{-1}>0$

So the convergenge is not uniform.

Answer (score 0):

For uniform convegance you must find first the limit of the sequence,in this case is $0$. So,until now you have proved that $f_n\to 0$ pointwisly.

For uniform con. you have to show that  $sup||f_n(x)-0|\to 0$. If this is true ,then we have uniform con.

Comment: So, would using that definition, sup|$x_n$ - 0|<$\epsilon$. If this were on (-1,1] I would choose $\epsilon$ = 1 since 1 is the greatest pointwise limit correct?

Comment: NO,you don't have to go by $ε$,in this one you can go with the limits

Answer (score 0):

It is pointwise convergent because there is a limit for every $x$. In this case, it turns out that the poinwise limit is the function $f(x)=0$, $x\in(-1,1)$. If you took the same sequence but on $(-1,1]$ the pointwise limit would be $f(x)=0$, $x\in(-1,1)$ and $f(1)=1$.
If a sequence uniformly converges then it converges pointwise. So, the only candidate for uniform limit is the pointwise limit. The definition of uniform convergence of a sequnce $(f_n(x))$ to $f(x)$:
$(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists n_0>0)(\forall x\in(-1,1))(\forall n) (n>n_0 \Rightarrow|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon)$
So, you are not supposed to choose an $\epsilon$.